# Unable to delete records as the transaction log file is full

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, archive, transaction-log

My disk is running out of space and as a result I decided to free some space by deleting old data. I tried to delete 100,000 by 100,000 as there are 240 million records to be deleted. But I am unable to delete them at once and shrinking the database doesn't free much space. This is the error im getting at times.

The transaction log for database 'TEST_ARCHIVE' is full. To find out why space in the log cannot be reused, see the log_reuse_wait_desc column in sys.databases

How can I overcome this situation and delete all the old records? Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

**Shrink Log File**

Your disk where your log file is located is full, try freeing up some space on the log drive.

```
Use [DatabaseName]
GO

CHECKPOINT;
GO

CHECKPOINT;  --<-- executed twice 
GO

DBCC SHRINKFILE('LogFileName' , 1024)
GO
```

**Delete Records in small Chunks**

Delete Records in small chunks something like ...

```
DECLARE @Deleted_Rows INT;
SET @Deleted_Rows = 1;


WHILE (@Deleted_Rows > 0)
  BEGIN
   -- Delete some small number of rows at a time
    DELETE TOP (10000) FROM [TableName]

  SET @Deleted_Rows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to need to backup the transaction log more frequently during a large delete operation.  A log backup will remove records from the transaction log that are no longer needed for rollback or crash recovery.  If that doesn't help, run the query suggested in the error message:

```
SELECT log_reuse_wait_desc
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = N'TEST_ARCHIVE';
```